# How to plot probability density function?

Tags: matlab

i want to plot probability density function for about 7500 data that shows peak ground acceleretion(PGA).what is the MATLAB code for this?thanks.

Comment: Hey! let me google that for you: "probability density function Matlab": http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/pdf.html.
then use plot().

Comment: I think the OP wants `hist`, not `pdf`

Comment: @LuisMendo The the OP is abit confused with nomenclature! :P good point though.

Comment: @mohamad: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, "give me the code" questions are not welcomed here. You'll want to do some of your own research and experimentation first, and then tell us what you have tried. We're here to give you direction, but you should assume you'll need to write the code yourself.

Comment: thanks jasonmc92 for your advise.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to *estimate* the probability densiry function from your data. That's a *histogram*, and for that you use the [`hist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function:

```
data = randn(1,7500); %// example data
n = 21; %// number of bins
[y, x] = hist(data, n);
y = y/(x(2)-x(1))/numel(data); %// normalize so that total area is 1
plot(x, y)
%// To check that area is approximately 1, compute the integral: trapz(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to know your distribution (for example Gaussian) you can do this:

```
data = randn(1,7500);
[mu sigma] = normfit(data);
X = mu - 10 : .1 : mu + 10;
Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma);
plot(X,Y);
```

And you could get this,

[image]

However if your data isn't Gaussian, you can use other fitting functions.